# I need to make a file of a specific size, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, file, byte, size

I have been assigned an exercise and I am facing some problems. About the exercise : I need to create a class with a method that creates a file of specific size (1733 bytes). Data should be added randomly to this file, but there is a static byte Array(aWeaved) with specific byte values that are allowed.

The way I understand it, is that I hava to create a byte Array with a size of 1733, and at each position I must add a value from -128 to 127, that is allowed by the aforementioned array. So I created the below code, but the size of the file is 1033. What am I doing wrong;

```
public class Jervina {
    public static byte[] aWeaved = {97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104,
        105, 49, 45, 50, 51, 52};
    public static long mAlbumen(String a) {
        ObjectOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(a)
                    ));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Random r = new Random();
        byte[] bts = new byte[1733];
        int count = 0;
        while (count != bts.length - 1) {
            bts[count] = (byte) (r.nextInt(256) - 128);
            for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
                if (aWeaved[i] == bts[count]) {
                    count++;
                    try {
                        output.writeByte(bts[count]);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is not about the size file but your `break` instruction should be into the `if (aWeaved[i] == bts[count]) { ... }` block. In the current state, it will test only the first value of your `aWeaved` array

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, the way you add randomly the allowed values is not efficient. You should generate a random index instead. So for this example, you have 14 allowed values, so you could generate a random int between 0 and 13 and pick the value at this random evaluated index.

Comment: @Imaguest You are absolutely right about the break, hadn't noticed. Thank you! As for the efficiency, your idea is very good actually but I'll keep as it is because it is just an exercise for the university and I prefer going with the Occam's Razor way.